# IOS call parent class method from subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, subclass

I am developing iPadd application. I use parent class for list and also use sub class for category selection. Subclass opening in popover. If user select any category from sub class then parent screen refresh with refreshScreenForiPad. So I want to call parentClass method What is refreshScreenForiPad. But i did not call. Please help me.

```
//ParentClass.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import SubClass;

@interface ParentClass : UIViewController{

}
-(void)refreshScreenForiPad;

---------------------


//SubClass.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ParentClass;

@interface SubClass : UIViewController{
ParentClass *_parentClass;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) ParentClass *parentClass;



//SubClass.m

@synthesize parentClass=_parentClass;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [self.parentClass refreshScreenForiPad];
}
```

Comment: And where do you assign your parentClass? maybe you calling 'refreshScreenForiPad' on nil ?

Comment: Are you actually trying to make a subclass of ParentClass? If not, the names are making your question a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the parentClass when the subClass is initialized..say

```
SubClass *subClass = [[SubClass alloc]init];
```

follow it with

```
sublass._parentClass = self;
```